# Spectrum of the product of two bounded operators

Tags: operator-theory, proof-explanation

> If $T$ is not invertible normal operator and $S$ is a bounded operator. Why $TS$ and $ST$ have the same spectrum?

**Proof:** Assume that $T$ is not invertible normal operator, then $0 \in \sigma(T)$.  Since $0$ is in the approximate point spectrum of $T$, it is clear that $0 \in \sigma(ST).$ Since $T$ is normal, it holds $\|Tx \| = \|T^*x \|$ for any vector $x$. Hence $0$ is in the approximate point spectrum of $T^*$ and hence $0 \in \sigma(S^*T^*) = \sigma((TS)^* = \overline{\sigma(TS)}$.  Hence $0 \in \sigma(TS)$.

Recall the following definition:

**Definition:** Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator of a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. The approximate point spectrum of $T$ is the set of all values $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that there exists a sequence of unit vectors $(x_n)_n\subset \mathcal{H}$ so that $\|(T-\lambda)x_n\|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: I think you should give more detail what exactly you dont understand, because there are multiple steps in the second case.

Comment: @supinf I don't understand why If $T$ is not invertible then  $0$ is in the approximate point spectrum of $T$? because $0 \in \sigma(T)$.

Comment: Your definition of approximate point spectrum includes the point spectrum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the assumption of normality, we can at least prove the following:

> If $T,S\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, then $\{0\}\cup\sigma(ST)=\{0\}\cup\sigma(TS)$.

(This holds more generally in unital Banach algebras.)  The second case is saying that $0$ is already in $\sigma(ST)$ and $\sigma(TS)$.

**EDIT**

This follows from the general statement:

> If $T\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is normal, then $\sigma(T)=\sigma_{ap}(T)$.

Indeed, fix $\lambda\in\sigma(T)$.  If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, we are done, so assume it is not, i.e., assume $\ker(T-\lambda)=\{0\}$.  Since $T$ is normal, we have $\ker(T^*-\overline\lambda)=\{0\}$, and thus
$$\overline{\operatorname{Range}(T-\lambda)}=\ker(T^*-\overline\lambda)^\perp=\mathcal{H}.$$
Hence $\operatorname{Range}(T-\lambda)$ is a proper dense subspace of $\mathcal{H}$. Thus $T-\lambda$ is not bounded below, and the result follows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know the jacobson Lemma. However I want to prove that if $T$ is normal then $\sigma(ST)=\sigma(TS)$

Comment: If $T$ is not invertible, then $0 \in \sigma(T)$.  But why $0$ is in the approximate point spectrum of $T$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I see.  I'm about to go to class, so I can't edit my answer just yet.  If nobody answers by the time I'm out I'll edit to answer your question.

Comment: Yes, but I haven't had time to reply.  I'll take a look at it later

Comment: @Schüler It looks like that approach assumes its result.  Here's how I would do it. If $T$ is invertible, split it up into two further cases: $S$ is invertible and $S$ is not invertible.  This allows you to control whether or not $0\in\sigma(ST)$ and $0\in\sigma(TS)$.